# std::string += operator cannot pass 0 as argument

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
std::string tmp;
tmp +=0;//compile error:ambiguous overload for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'int')
tmp +=1;//ok
tmp += '\0';//ok...expected
tmp +=INT_MAX;//ok
tmp +=int(INT_MAX);//still ok...what?
```

The first one argues that passing integer as argument, right? Why others passes compilation?I tested on Visual C++ and g++, and I got the same result above. So I believe I miss something defined by standard. What is it?

Comment: `int` will be converted to `char`. but for `0` its difficult to say whether its `NULL` or `int 0`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is that a literal 0 is a *null pointer constant*.  The compiler doesn't know if you meant:

```
std::string::operator +=(const char*);  // tmp += "abc";
```

or

```
std::string::operator +=(char);         // tmp += 'a';
```

(better compilers list the options).

The workround (as you have discovered) is to write the append as:

```
tmp += '\0';
```

(I assume you didn't want the string version - `tmp += nullptr;` would be UB at runtime.)

Comment: Should the compiler really consider `+=(char)`?

Comment: Yes.  `char` is a integral type, and an integer is implicitly convertable to char.  `+=(char)` is the overload that is being invoked in *all* the non-ambiguous cases.

Answer (score 11):

The `0` literal is implicitly convertible to all pointer types (resulting in their respective null pointer constants). Therefore it results in two equally valid conversion sequences for matching `std::string`s appending operator.